# Is there a way to disable MotionLayout visiblity changes animation?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my MotionScene I have transition which lasts for several seconds. In ConstraintSet I have a view that is invisible that I want to make visible when the transition is done. But I don't want to animate the view going from `Visibility.GONE` to `Visibility.VISIBLE`. Is there a way to stop that?

If needed I can provide code, but it's not that complex. It's just a transition with two ConstraintSet-s, this View is in both sets in starting set it's `visibility="visible"`, and in ending set it's `visibility = "gone"`

Does anybody have any suggestions?

EDIT: I should note that I did put 
    `android:animateLayoutChanges="false"` in root layout of the activity that uses this MotionScene.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem, you can use alpha animation like this;

```
AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0.3f);
animation1.setDuration(1000);
animation1.setFillAfter(true);
yourView.startAnimation(animation1);
```